# Check if there is an <tr> underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that adds me an extra input each time I write something in it.
but I have the problem that even if in the input is already something written and I change it it adds an new input. 
But I would like to disable that.

I tried an if check but I am not so familiar whit html so I don't know how to perform this check like I want it.

Can someone tell me how to check if there is an object underneath the input box I am changing

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    $('<tr><td><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></tr></td>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });
  
  $(".iptArea").live("change", function() {
 
    $('<tr><td><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></tr></td>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
 
    return false;

  });

  $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $(this).parents('tr').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h2><a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/0hcod561/1/show/light/#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
 <tr>
 <td>
      <label for="p_scnts">
        <input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value">
      </label>
 </td>
 </tr>
</div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an invalid HTML.

Comment: `p_scnts`, `p_scnt`, `p_scents`... I think you need to make up your mind on which name to use. Also: id attributes have to have unique values in your document. You'll get unexpected results if you select nodes by id and have duplicates.

Comment: yes i know I know the original code isn't mine I just modified it a little. I will do that later on when it is working. @trincot

Comment: You're using jQuery 1.4? You should [upgrade](https://jquery.org/history/) to at least ... 1.11

Comment: hmm don't know each time I try an other version it doesn't work. @trincot

Comment: Indeed, it wont work just like that, but there is a [migration plug-in](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable#readme) you can use which in development mode gives console messages whenever you use something that needs upgrading. Better do it asap, ... the longer you wait, the more difficult migration becomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- There are `tr` tags outside of `table` tags -- this is invalid HTML; `div` is not the right container;
- jQuery 1.4 is really outdated, and the `live` method is deprecated;
- the `for` attribute has a value which refers to a non-existing element. Probably it should read `for="p_scnt"` instead of `for="p_scnts"`;
- there is duplication of code in the first two event handlers;
- the template HTML which you insert has mistakes:

  - the closing `</tr>` and `</td>` tags are in the wrong order;
  - the input's `id` property has the same value as an already existing element -- this is not allowed in HTML and can lead to unexpected behaviour of scripts;
  - the same issue with the `for` attribute appears here;
  - you can better place template HTML inside the HTML document, in
    an invisible container. That makes it easier to manage.

To prevent rows from being added when there is already an empty input in the last row, you could use this test:

```
$('#p_scents .iptArea').last().val() === ''
```

Here is the corrected code, which also includes that test:

```js
$(function() {
    var uniqueId = 1;
    
    function addRow() {
        var html = $('#template > tbody').html().replace(/\$/g, uniqueId++);
        $('#p_scents > tbody').append(html.trim());
        return false;
    }

    $('#addScnt').click(addRow);
    
    $(document).delegate('.iptArea', 'change', function () {
        if ($('#p_scents .iptArea').last().val() === '') return false; // don't add
        return addRow();
    });

    $(document).delegate('.remScnt', 'click', function(e) {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
<h2>
   <a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/0hcod561/1/show/light/#" id="addScnt">
      Add Another Input Box
   </a>
</h2>

<table style="display:none" id="template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="p_scnt_$">
                <input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt_$"     
                        size="20" name="p_scnt_$" value="" placeholder="Input Value">
            </label>
            <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table  id="p_scents">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="p_scnt">
                <input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt" 
                        size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value">
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could also consider responding to the `input` event, adding that word after `change`, like this:

```
$(document).delegate('.iptArea', 'change input', function () {
```

This will trigger at every change, not only when you change focus.

Note that I have converted your calls to `.live()` to `.delegate()`, as `.live()` is not supported at all in newer versions of jQuery (> 1.9), while `.delegate()` works (still) in all 1.x versions. But take note of [the docs on `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation.

But `on` does not exist in jQuery 1.4, so `delegate` is the best compromise until you have fully migrated your code. As stated in [the docs on `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9
>
> Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

#### After having migrated to current jQuery version

Then change `.delegate()` calls to `.on()` calls, and swap the first two arguments in those calls, for instance:

```
    $(document).on('change input', '.iptArea', function () { // .. etc
```

Here is the same snippet, but running with jQuery 2.2

```js
$(function() {
    var uniqueId = 1;
    
    function addRow() {
        var html = $('#template > tbody').html().replace(/\$/g, uniqueId++);
        $('#p_scents > tbody').append(html.trim());
        return false;
    }

    $('#addScnt').click(addRow);
    
    $(document).on('change', '.iptArea', function () {
        if ($('#p_scents .iptArea').last().val() === '') return false; // don't add
        return addRow();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function(e) {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
<h2>
   <a href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/0hcod561/1/show/light/#" id="addScnt">
      Add Another Input Box
   </a>
</h2>

<table style="display:none" id="template">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="p_scnt_$">
                <input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt_$"     
                        size="20" name="p_scnt_$" value="" placeholder="Input Value">
            </label>
            <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table  id="p_scents">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="p_scnt">
                <input type="text" class="iptArea" id="p_scnt" 
                        size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value">
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wow thanks it works fine 10/10 would give you 1 million points if I could. I changed the jQuery to 2.2.3 it stills works fine.

Comment: Great to hear. If you have successfully migrated to 2.2.3, then it would be good if you would replace the calls to `.delegate(a,b,c)` with `.on(b,a,c)`, meaning you need to swap the first two arguments. That way you have code as it is supposed to be with the latest jQuery versions :-)

Comment: I changed .delegate to .on but it don't works do I also have to change something else?

Comment: Swapped the arguments? I added the changed code to my answer as a working snippet based on jQuery 2.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there's a row (`tr`) after the row an `input` element is in:

```
var has_row_after = $( 'input' ).closest('tr').next().is('tr');
```

Comment: I tried it like this but it stops working at the 3rd row                                              `if ( $( 'input' ).closest('tr').next().is('tr') == false) {}`

Comment: Your not supposed to actually use `$( 'input' )`, but rather the jQuery object that contains the `input` in which you want to check if there's a row after it's containing row.